# A Div ultrapassa o tamanho da Section

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, layout-responsivo

Tenho uma div chamada 'banner' que está dentro de uma section que chamo de 'bg'.
Quando diminuo  tela em termos de altura, o banner ultrapassa o tamanho do bg.

```css
*{
 font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}
html{width:100%;
 height:100%;
}
body{
 background-color: #d9d9d9;
 width:100%;
 height:100%;
 /* border: 9px solid red; */
}
.material-icons{
 position:relative;
 top: 20px;
 left: 2px;
 font-weight:900;
 font-size: 50px;
}
.fonte{
 font-family: 'Lobster', cursive;
 font-weight: bolder;
 font-size: 36px;}
.navegacao-bar{
 background-color:white;
}
.nav-link:hover{
 background-color: #fdec00;
}
.marca{
 padding-left: 30px;
}
.divisor{
 height: 15px;
 background-color: rgb(245, 248, 70);
}
.bg{
 background-image: url("imagem/cidade.jpg");
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-size:cover;
 height: calc(100% - 122px);
 /* border: 4px solid rgb(255, 72, 0); */
}
.slogan p{
 font-family: 'Lobster', cursive;
 font-size: 50px;
 color:rgb(230, 248, 70);
}
.button-home{
 position: relative;
 width: 15%;
 top: 14%;
 left: 42%;
}
.button-home button{
 width:250px;
 height:60px;
 background-color:rgb(236, 248, 70);
 margin-bottom: 5px;
 color: rgb(31, 30, 30);
 font-size: 24px;
 border-color: rgb(248, 236, 70);
}
.banner{
 position: relative;
 margin:auto;
 background: rgba(20, 20, 20, 0.555);
 padding-top:10px;
 padding-bottom:80px;
 padding-left:100px;
 padding-right:100px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
     <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

     <title>Barra de Navegação Bootstrap</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap CDN -->
   <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous"> -->
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <!-- Fontes -->
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster" rel="stylesheet">



  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons"
   rel="stylesheet">
   <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans" rel="stylesheet">     <!--[if lt IE 9]>
       <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
       <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
     <![endif]-->

 <!-- CSS-->
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="achei.css">
 </head>
 <body>
  <div class="navegacao-bar"> 
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-transparent">
   <div class="container-fluid">
     <div class="marca">
       <p class="fonte navbar-brand">Ach<i class="material-icons">search</i>u</p>
       <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#barra-navegacao" aria-controls="conteudoNavbarSuportado" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Alterna navegação">
         <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
     </div>
     <ul id="barra-navegacao" class="nav justify-content-end collapse navbar-collapse">
       <li class="nav-link" href="#">Dashboard</li>      
       <li class="nav-link">Registros</li>       
       <li class="nav-link">Mapa</li>
       <div class="dropdown">
        <li class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" id="navbar-menu" aria-haspopup="true" 
        aria-expanded="false"  href="#">Minha Area</li>
         <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbar-menu">
          <li class="dropdown-item" href="#">Editar</li>
          <li class="dropdown-item" href="#">Sair</li>
         </div>
       </div>
     </ul>
   </div> <!--container-->
  </nav>
  </div>
  <div class="divisor"></div>
  
  <section class="container-fluid bg  d-flex flex-column">
    <div class="banner">
      <div class="slogan d-flex flex-column align-items-center">
        <p>Olá</p>
        <p>Blá</p>
        <p>Blá</p>
      </div>
      <div class="button-home d-flex flex-column align-items-center">
       <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark btn-lg "aria-pressed="true">Inscrever-se</button>
       <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark btn-lg "aria-pressed="true">Entrar</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
     
  <!-- JS Bootstrap -->  
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recriei a sua página com o bootstrap, espero que possa te ajudar.
Sugiro que você procure um pouco mais sobre as classes do flexbox, irá organizar melhor o seu código.

```css
html,body{
    height: 100% !important;
}
.container-fluid{
    padding: 0 !important;
    height: calc(100% - 122px) !important;
}
.divisor{
    height: 15px;
    background: yellow;
}

.second{
    background: url('https://imgnooz.com/sites/default/files/wallpaper/travel/66746/new-york-under-bridge-wallpapers-66746-2947804.jpg');
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    min-height: 400px;
    text-align: center;
}
.central{
    background: yellow;
    width: 20%;
    min-width: 200px;
    padding: 2rem;
    display: block;
}
.btn{
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto !important;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm"
        crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- Custom CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

    <title>Hello, world!</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container-fluid firstContainer">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent"
                aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>

            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                    <li class="nav-item active">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown"
                            aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                            Dropdown
                        </a>
                        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                            <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
                    <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
                    <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </nav>
        <div class="divisor">

        </div>
        <div class="container-fluid second">
            <div class="central">
                <div class="textos">
                    <h2>Bom</h2>
                    <h2>Bom</h2>
                    <h2>Bom</h2>
                </div>
                <div class="botoes">
                    <button class="btn btn-warn">
                        Inscrever-se
                    </button>
                    <button class="btn btn-warn">
                        Entrar
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Troque o `height: calc(100% - 122px)` por `min-height: 100%`. Isso porque ao utilizar o `calc`, quando a altura do viewport (área da janela) for menor que a altura do documento, o `calc` irá descontar `122px`, fazendo com que a div fique menor que a altura do viewport. Com o `min-height`, a altura da div irá sempre acompanhar a altura da janela.

```css
*{
 font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}
html{width:100%;
 height:100%;
}
body{
 background-color: #d9d9d9;
 width:100%;
 height:100%;
 /* border: 9px solid red; */
}
.material-icons{
 position:relative;
 top: 20px;
 left: 2px;
 font-weight:900;
 font-size: 50px;
}
.fonte{
 font-family: 'Lobster', cursive;
 font-weight: bolder;
 font-size: 36px;}
.navegacao-bar{
 background-color:white;
}
.nav-link:hover{
 background-color: #fdec00;
}
.marca{
 padding-left: 30px;
}
.divisor{
 height: 15px;
 background-color: rgb(245, 248, 70);
}
.bg{
 background-image: url("https://www.cleverfiles.com/howto/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/mini.jpg");
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-size:cover;
 /*height: calc(100% - 122px);*/
   min-height: 100%;
 /* border: 4px solid rgb(255, 72, 0); */
}
.slogan p{
 font-family: 'Lobster', cursive;
 font-size: 50px;
 color:rgb(230, 248, 70);
}
.button-home{
 position: relative;
 width: 15%;
 top: 14%;
 left: 42%;
}
.button-home button{
 width:250px;
 height:60px;
 background-color:rgb(236, 248, 70);
 margin-bottom: 5px;
 color: rgb(31, 30, 30);
 font-size: 24px;
 border-color: rgb(248, 236, 70);
}
.banner{
 position: relative;
 margin:auto;
 background: rgba(20, 20, 20, 0.555);
 padding-top:10px;
 padding-bottom:80px;
 padding-left:100px;
 padding-right:100px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
     <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

     <title>Barra de Navegação Bootstrap</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap CDN -->
   <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous"> -->
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <!-- Fontes -->
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster" rel="stylesheet">



  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons"
   rel="stylesheet">
   <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans" rel="stylesheet">     <!--[if lt IE 9]>
       <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
       <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
     <![endif]-->

 <!-- CSS-->
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="achei.css">
 </head>
 <body>
  <div class="navegacao-bar"> 
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-transparent">
   <div class="container-fluid">
     <div class="marca">
       <p class="fonte navbar-brand">Ach<i class="material-icons">search</i>u</p>
       <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#barra-navegacao" aria-controls="conteudoNavbarSuportado" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Alterna navegação">
         <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
     </div>
     <ul id="barra-navegacao" class="nav justify-content-end collapse navbar-collapse">
       <li class="nav-link" href="#">Dashboard</li>      
       <li class="nav-link">Registros</li>       
       <li class="nav-link">Mapa</li>
       <div class="dropdown">
        <li class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" id="navbar-menu" aria-haspopup="true" 
        aria-expanded="false"  href="#">Minha Area</li>
         <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbar-menu">
          <li class="dropdown-item" href="#">Editar</li>
          <li class="dropdown-item" href="#">Sair</li>
         </div>
       </div>
     </ul>
   </div> <!--container-->
  </nav>
  </div>
  <div class="divisor"></div>
  
  <section class="container-fluid bg  d-flex flex-column">
    <div class="banner">
      <div class="slogan d-flex flex-column align-items-center">
        <p>Olá</p>
        <p>Blá</p>
        <p>Blá</p>
      </div>
      <div class="button-home d-flex flex-column align-items-center">
       <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark btn-lg "aria-pressed="true">Inscrever-se</button>
       <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark btn-lg "aria-pressed="true">Entrar</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
     
  <!-- JS Bootstrap -->  
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Entendi. Vlw deu certo agora